# is there a clear understanding of IQWidgets library

Tags: ios, objective-c, gantt-chart

I am trying to build a gantt chart.
I found this library on https://github.com/evolvIQ/iqwidgets

I download it, I tried to understand how can I use it.

I have a class that bring the data(JSON) from a server. I am assigning these results as `[NSDictionary]`.

I tried to use the `IQGanttView.h` file by adding it as a subview of my current view.
`IQGanttView.h` has a method called `addRow:(id<IQCalendarDataSource>)row`

The `addRow` method has an argument of `IQCalendarDataSource` which is why I created a class as an `IQCalendarDataSource` (Task object). 
I change the `IQCalendarDataSource` class to have the same property of my task class.

After creating these tasks object, I have a for loop for all the array(tasks object) to add them through `addRow:(id<IQCalendarDataSource>)row` method to show up on the chart.

I ran the code and followed it but it's not showing me the tasks on the chart.

I don't know if i'm missing something?
Can someone check the library and tell me if i'm missing something?

=================

This is the code that I was trying.

```
#import "GanttChartViewController.h"
#import "ASRESTAPI.h"
#import "ASUserSingleton.h"
#import "TasksObj.h"
#import "IQGanttView.h"

// when the view load I want to show the user the loading view until the data is ready to show up on the chart by calling [self setupLoadingIndicator] method
// 
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tasksItems = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    self.ganttView = [[IQGanttView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:self.ganttView];
    [self setupLoadingIndicator];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the
    [self gettheTasksItems];
}

-(void)setupLoadingIndicator
{
    loadingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 155, 170, 170)];
    loadingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
    loadingView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    loadingView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;

    activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    activityView.frame = CGRectMake(65, 40, activityView.bounds.size.width, activityView.bounds.size.height);
    [loadingView addSubview:activityView];

    loadingLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 115, 130, 22)];
    loadingLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    loadingLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    loadingLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    loadingLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    loadingLabel.text = @"Loading...";
    [loadingView addSubview:loadingLabel];
    [self.ganttView addSubview:loadingView];
    [activityView startAnimating];
}


-(void)gettheTasksItems
{

    NSString* username = [[ASUserSingleton sharedInstance]userName];
    NSString* password = [[ASUserSingleton sharedInstance]password];
    _tasks = nil;
    [ASRESTAPI tasksListUsername:username andPassword:password completionBlock:^(NSDictionary *response, NSArray *taskArray) {
        _tasks = response;
        tasksItems = taskArray;

        NSMutableArray *tasksObjs = [NSMutableArray array];
        int i;
        for (i =0; i < tasksItems.count;i++)
        {
            /*_tasks[@"project"][@"name"]*/ // this is how to call the dictionary object from the array
            TasksObj* tasksObj = [[TasksObj alloc]initWithProjectName:tasksItems[i][@"project"][@"name"]
                                                               startDate:tasksItems[i][@"start_date"]
                                                                 dueDate:tasksItems[i][@"due_date"]
                                                          estimatedhours:tasksItems[i][@"estimated_hours"]];
            //tasksItems[i] objectForKey:@"project"];
            [tasksObjs addObject:tasksObj];
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [activityView stopAnimating];
            for (loadingView in [self.ganttView subviews])
            {
                [loadingView removeFromSuperview];
            }
            //[loadingView removeFromSuperview];
            for (TasksObj* tasksObj in tasksObjs) {
                [self.ganttView addRow:tasksObj];
            }

        });

    }];
}
```

The reason that I'm using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()` is to make sure that the UI element is shown, i've learned that if I want the UI element to be shown then I have to make it through the main queue.

This is the class of TasksObj

```
@interface TasksObj : NSObject <IQCalendarDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* projectName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate* start_date;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate* due_date;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber* estimated_hours;

-(id)initWithProjectName:(NSString*)projectName startDate:(NSDate*)start_date dueDate:(NSDate*)due_date estimatedhours:(NSNumber*)estimated_hours;

@end

@implementation TasksObj

-(id)initWithProjectName:(NSString*)projectName startDate:(NSDate*)start_date dueDate:(NSDate*)due_date estimatedhours:(NSNumber*)estimated_hours
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.projectName = projectName;
        self.start_date = start_date;
        self.due_date = due_date;
        self.estimated_hours = estimated_hours;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

by the way this is the JSON data that i'm getting from the server

```
 "task":
 {
 "id":1,
 "project":{"id":1,"name":"test"},
 "tracker":{"id":1,"name":"Bug"},
 "status":{"id":1,"name":"New"},
 "priority":{"id":4,"name":"Urgent"},
 "author":{"id":1,"name":"the user name"},
 "subject":"Example",
 "description":"",
 "start_date":"2016-02-17",
 "due_date":"2016-02-23",
 "done_ratio":0,
 "estimated_hours":3.0,
 "spent_hours":0.0,
 "created_on":"2016-02-18T04:28:55Z",
 "updated_on":"2016-02-22T19:09:22Z"
 }
```

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Comment: Ok, I will edit my post so you can check it out. Thank you for your comment!! really thank you.